# Google appengine java AppSatori pipes fork/join java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: eu.appsatori.pipes.Node

Tags: java, eclipse, node.js, google-app-engine

I need to use parallel programation in Google appengine for java so i use  AppSatori pipes fork/join in simple exemple wich i found in 
[Introduction
Fork-Join Example](https://github.com/musketyr/appsatori-pipes)

but i have  after runnig an  **error**  :

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: eu.appsatori.pipes.Node 
i use jre 1.7
pipes 0.6.0 
eclipse juno sr1
windows 7 64bits
```

i never create a Node.It is a default classe or I muste create it.Can one help me to have exemple for paralle programme in google appengine or to resolve this propleme.And think you in advice.

Comment: Ar you using any IDE.. ? Eclipse or NetBeans or smthg like that..?..

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because `Node` **isn't a class, it's an interface**. You will have to implement that interface like :

```
public class Foo implements Node{
}
```

Check this reference : [Node.java](https://github.com/musketyr/appsatori-pipes/blob/master/src/main/java/eu/appsatori/pipes/Node.java)